# React query not executing second block of api call

Tags: reactjs, react-query

apis

```
  export const useAccountData = (
    address: string,
    options?: UseQueryOptions<IQuery, AxiosError>
  ) =>
    useQuery(
      createUseAddressKey(address),
      () =>
        fetcherAddressArkhamTransfers(`api/transfers`, address).then(
          ({ data }) => data
        ),
      {
        ...options,
        retry: false,
        cacheTime: MINUTES_TO_REFETCH_DATA,
        staleTime: MINUTES_TO_REFETCH_DATA,
      }
    );

  export const usePortfolioData = (
    address: string,
    options?: UseQueryOptions<IQuery, AxiosError>
  ) =>
    useQuery(
      createUseAddressKey(address),
      () =>
        fetcherAddressArkhamTransfers(`api/portfolios`, address).then(
          ({ data }) => data
        ),
      {
        ...options,
        retry: false,
        cacheTime: MINUTES_TO_REFETCH_DATA,
        staleTime: MINUTES_TO_REFETCH_DATA,
      }
    );
```

Using React Query

```
  const {
    data: query,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useAccountData(Account, {
    enabled: router.isReady,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });

  const { data: portfolios } = usePortfolioData(Account, {
    enabled: router.isReady,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });
```

Here my 1st block is working but, second block portfolio one is not working.
I am using react - query for that.
I checked in network tab only transfers api call is going

Please  take a look

Comment: u should use a different `query key` for every single query hook.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have defined two separate API calls using the `useAccountData` and `usePortfolioData` hooks. While the `useAccountData` call is working correctly, **the `usePortfolioData` call is not**.

In my view, one possible reason for this issue is that

> *`createUseAddressKey` function used in both API calls is creating the same key for both of them. As a result, the second call is overwriting the first one.*

To fix this issue, you can modify the `createUseAddressKey` function to include a prefix that differentiates between the two calls. For example:

```js
const createUseAddressKey = (address: string, prefix: string) =>
  `use${prefix}Data_${address}`;
```

Then, when you call the `useAccountData` and `usePortfolioData` functions, you can pass in a unique prefix for each call. For example:

```
const { data: query, isLoading, isError, error } = useAccountData(Account, {
    enabled: router.isReady,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
}, "account"); // <--- account is the prefix argument here for createUseAddressKey

const { data: portfolios } = usePortfolioData(Account, {
  enabled: router.isReady,
  refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
}, "portfolio"); // <--- portfolio is the argument here for createUseAddressKey
```

*By using different prefixes for the two API calls, you should be able to make both calls without overwriting each other.*